# Class not found using javaConfig

Tags: java, spring

I am using annotations to dynamically create a Bean, I get the following errors.

```
package demoproject;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
@Configuration
public class ProductFactory {

    public ProductFactory() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Bean   
    public Product josh(){
        Product josh = new Battery();
        josh.setId("cdrw");
        josh.setPrice(100);
        return josh;
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
 <!-- Bean for JavaConfig -->
   <bean  class='demoproject.ProductFactory' />
   <!-- be sure to include the JavaConfig bean post-processor -->
   <bean class="org.springframework.config.java.process.ConfigurationPostProcessor"/>
```

Error log

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.config.java.process.ConfigurationPostProcessor] for bean with name 'org.springframework.config.java.process.ConfigurationPostProcessor#0' defined in class path resource [web.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.config.java.process.ConfigurationPostProcessor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:910)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at demoproject.ProductCreater.main(ProductCreater.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.config.java.process.ConfigurationPostProcessor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:260)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1267)
    ... 9 more
```

How can I know what's causing the error, and is there any fix I can try for this?

Comment: Got it I hadnt told spring to look for annotation and scan themy package

Answer (score 19):

from spring 3.0 on, you don't need **org.springframework.config.java.process.ConfigurationPostProcessor** any more, simply define the Java-config class as a bean within the XML-config.

```
<bean class="demoproject.ProductFactory" />
```

try remove

```
<bean class="org.springframework.config.java.process.ConfigurationPostProcessor"/>
```

Comment: I am using spring 3.2. Same error saying the bean josh is not defined

Comment: Thanks. I got out-of-date info until I see this post.

Comment: why it's not updated on spring documentation

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `spring-core` on your runtime classpath. You need to add it using the appropriate technique for your project layout, such as by adding it to a Maven POM like Simon suggests.

Comment: Removed the comment, since it is quite similar to another question and I think they reworked that a bit in spring 3. Of course he might be using an older version of Spring.

Comment: He is still using XML-based configuration, so there's no telling.

Comment: This is spring 3.2. I tried with the accepted answer marked as accepted in the duplicate question. now I get "No bean named 'josh' is defined"