# I'm trying to do basic CRUD in Spring 4 MVC with hibernate--How to do dependency injection in SPRING 4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

******Controller:******

```
package com.wipro.pr316445.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.wipro.pr316445.entity.Person;
import com.wipro.pr316445.service.PersonService;
import com.wipro.pr316445.service.PersonServiceImpl;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("userSession")
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/listOperations")
    public ModelAndView user(){
        return new ModelAndView("listOperations");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/addPersonDisplay")
    public ModelAndView addPersonDisplay(@ModelAttribute("person") @Valid Person person, BindingResult result){
        return new ModelAndView("addPerson");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/addPerson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") @Valid Person person, BindingResult result, 
            ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String msg;
        boolean res;
        if(!result.hasErrors()) {

            res=personService.addPerson(person);
            msg="Person details successfully added!";
        }
        else{
            msg="Please check the data you've entered!";
        }
        return new ModelAndView("addPerson","message",msg);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="personById")
    public String getPersonById(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        int pid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pid"));
        Person person = personService.getPersonById(pid);

        model.addAttribute(person);     
        return "personform";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="updatePerson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updatePerson(@ModelAttribute("person") @Valid Person person, BindingResult result,
            ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        if(!result.hasErrors()) {
            personService.updatePerson(person);
            model.addAttribute(new Person());
            model.addAttribute("msg", "Person updated successfully.");
        }

        return "personform";
    }   
    @RequestMapping(value="deletePerson")
    public String deletePerson(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        int pid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pid"));
        personService.deletePerson(pid);
        model.addAttribute(new Person());
        model.addAttribute("msg","Person deleted successfully.");

        return "personform";
    }



}
```

******Service Implementation:******

```
package com.wipro.pr316445.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.wipro.pr316445.dao.PersonDao;
import com.wipro.pr316445.entity.Person;

@Service("personService")
@Transactional(propagation= Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

    @Autowired
    private PersonDao personDao;

    @Override
    public List<Person> getAllPersons() {
        return personDao.getAllPersons();
    }

    @Override
    public Person getPersonById(int pid) {
        Person obj = personDao.getPersonById(pid);
        return obj;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addPerson(Person person) {
        return personDao.addPerson(person);
    }

    @Override
    public void updatePerson(Person person) {
        personDao.updatePerson(person);
    }

    @Override
    public void deletePerson(int pid) {
        personDao.deletePerson(pid);
    }

}
```

******Dao Implementation******

```
package com.wipro.pr316445.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.wipro.pr316445.entity.Person;


@Repository("personDao")
public class PersonDaoImpl implements PersonDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Person> getAllPersons() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Person getPersonById(int pid) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addPerson(Person person) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(person);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void updatePerson(Person person) {

    }

    @Override
    public void deletePerson(int pid) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean personExists(String username) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

**AppConfig**

```
package com.wipro.pr316445.config;

import java.util.Locale;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import com.wipro.pr316445.controller.PersonController;
import com.wipro.pr316445.dao.PersonDao;
import com.wipro.pr316445.dao.PersonDaoImpl;
import com.wipro.pr316445.service.PersonService;
import com.wipro.pr316445.service.PersonServiceImpl;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.wipro.pr316445")
@Import(DBConfig.class)
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean  
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {  
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();  
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");  
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;  
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
        CookieLocaleResolver resolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en"));
        resolver.setCookieName("myLocaleCookie");
        resolver.setCookieMaxAge(4800);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        interceptor.setParamName("mylocale");
        registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    }  

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/app-resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }  

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }

}
```

****Error while starting tomcat server****

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'personService': Error creating bean with name 'personService' defined in file [D:\Studies\TopGear\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\Sample\WEB-INF\classes\com\wipro\pr316445\service\PersonServiceImpl.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getQualifiedMethodName(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/String;; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personService' defined in file [D:\Studies\TopGear\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\Sample\WEB-INF\classes\com\wipro\pr316445\service\PersonServiceImpl.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getQualifiedMethodName(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/String;
Nov 24, 2016 12:32:29 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'personService': Error creating bean with name 'personService' defined in file [D:\Studies\TopGear\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\Sample\WEB-INF\classes\com\wipro\pr316445\service\PersonServiceImpl.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getQualifiedMethodName(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/String;; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personService' defined in file [D:\Studies\TopGear\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\Sample\WEB-INF\classes\com\wipro\pr316445\service\PersonServiceImpl.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getQualifiedMethodName(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4851)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personService' defined in file [D:\Studies\TopGear\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\Sample\WEB-INF\classes\com\wipro\pr316445\service\PersonServiceImpl.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getQualifiedMethodName(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1048)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getQualifiedMethodName(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.getTransactionAttribute(AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.java:106)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSourcePointcut.matches(TransactionAttributeSourcePointcut.java:41)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:279)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:311)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:347)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    ... 34 more

Nov 24, 2016 12:32:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'personService': Error creating bean with name 'personService' defined in file [D:\Studies\TopGear\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\Sample\WEB-INF\classes\com\wipro\pr316445\service\PersonServiceImpl.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getQualifiedMethodName(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/String;; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personService' defined in file [D:\Studies\TopGear\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\Sample\WEB-INF\classes\com\wipro\pr316445\service\PersonServiceImpl.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getQualifiedMethodName(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4851)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personService' defined in file [D:\Studies\TopGear\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\Sample\WEB-INF\classes\com\wipro\pr316445\service\PersonServiceImpl.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getQualifiedMethodName(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1048)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getQualifiedMethodName(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.getTransactionAttribute(AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.java:106)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSourcePointcut.matches(TransactionAttributeSourcePointcut.java:41)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:279)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:311)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:347)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    ... 34 more
```

Whenever I try to add dependency and start the server I facing this issue. Help me with this. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Spring @Autowired usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414734/understanding-spring-autowired-usage)

Comment: Post your WEB-INF/lib or pom

Answer (score 1):

The actual error you're getting is

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getQualifiedMethodName

A quick search leads to another question on Stack Overflow:

[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465906/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-util-classutils-fornameljava)

That isn't quite the error you got, but close enough: the problem is that your Spring jar files aren't all from the same version of Spring. In your case it looks like you have mismatching spring-core and spring-beans versions.