# NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.identityToString(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String

Tags: java, spring, tomcat8

I am using spring xml way and ANT tool earlier it was jdk source and target version 1.5 now i am converting into java1.7 and creating war and i have upgaraded tomcate configuration with tomcat 8 , after changes in server.xml, catalina.properties and web.xml.   below is my catalina.out log

```
NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.identityToString(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String



18-Jan-2020 20:15:15.229 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
18-Jan-2020 20:15:15.401 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
18-Jan-2020 20:15:15.493 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Could not instantiate class [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext]; constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.identityToString(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.identityToString(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:161)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:211)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:81)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:51)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.<init>(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:250)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4699)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5165)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18-Jan-2020 20:15:15.501 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
18-Jan-2020 20:15:15.512 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/omega] startup failed due to previous errors
18-Jan-2020 20:15:15.821 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [omega] registered the JDBC driver [org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
18-Jan-2020 20:15:15.827 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [omega] registered the JDBC driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
18-Jan-2020 20:15:15.847 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/home/surya8db/omega/omega/webapps/omega.war] has finished in [10,616] ms
18-Jan-2020 20:15:15.853 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-11122"]
18-Jan-2020 20:15:15.875 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
18-Jan-2020 20:15:15.880 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 10696 ms
```

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using?

Comment: I am using spring 3 older version

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465906/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-util-classutils-fornameljava
This will help

Comment: Try above mentioned link or updating Spring version